# CakePHP sort confusing me

Tags: sorting, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Why in my queries I must use the key `order`, but in contain, or in Table I must use sort? It's a little confusing me and moreover this is not indicated in the `fr` doc, maybe in the `eng` doc?

Does someone know why these choices of naming?

Comment: This is mainly historical.

Comment: @mark is the core supporting `sort` and `order` in the places he named? Feels somehow awkward and inconsistent to rely on the old naming given the fact a lot other old things where refactored.

Comment: interesting, I guess it will be removed overtime.

Answer (score 0):

I will start quoting an answer from stack exchange for english grammar:

> "Sort" and "order" are generally interchangeable, and in your example, they are perfect synonyms. The one difference is that "order" can only be used for things that actually have a pre-defined ordering, like alphabetical or numeric. I could ask you to sort buttons by color, but asking you to order them by color wouldn't make much sense.

It's more natural when you use in your queries the word "order" because table columns are meant to store values with a pre-defined order like dates, ids, last names.
And sort is more generic and that is my theory of why used in other parts of the framework.

Not sure if was something planed or just was the natural development of the framework, maybe you could try to ask one of the core contributors and ask him about the decision.

Answer (score -1):

I think "sort" is used primarily for pagination and "order" is used for the initial query perhaps. In standard MYSQL there is no "SORT" so it's just how Cake decides to differentiate the two.